# error: Instance member ['addMultipleCollection'] can't be accessed using static access. Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a firebase project, I am trying to add a subcollection everytime the user presses a button. When calling the function, I get the given error. Both files are imported and I do not understand what the error means

[This is where I am calling the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj3XH.png)

[And this is the function itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPtSL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using DatabaseService instance.

```dart
DatabaseService().addMultipleCollection(duration);
```